# What is the name of the glyph that looks like a dash, but tapers on a single end?

Tags: terminology, symbols, unicode

What is the name of the symbol shown below used to sometimes stylize page numbering or to call attention to an item in the page? It's hard to explain with words, but here's a picture.

[image: dashes similar to em- or en-dash]

Does this have a name? It looks like a dash with a tapered end. I'm looking for the general name of this type of dash, the unicode value, or for information about the font family that it is tied to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These glyphs are part of **Adobe Wood Type Ornaments**

[image]

You can read more about these glyphs [here](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/wood-type-ornaments/regular/#glyphs/511111/99). I don't think they have a unicode value, but you can access them via the Character Viewer in OSX or the Glyphs panel in Adobe software.

Comment: And they are typically called "ornaments" as well.

Comment: Thanks Alex that helped immensely. The character codes for the left and right ornaments imaged above under Windows is: 0x63 (ALT+099 decimal) and 0x43 (ALT+067 decimal) in the Woodtype Ornaments 2 family.